# A web app with logins in a kiosk situation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, kiosk

We are looking at setting up an internal web application (ASP.NET MVC) as a kiosk for the employees that don't have a dedicated computer. We currently do not have this kiosk setup. Each employee will have their own login to look at some basic payroll information and request leaves of absence. This same web application will be used by the office workers with a dedicated PC at their desk.

I am going to go out on a limb and say that no matter how many times we tell the employees, the employees will not click log off when they walk away from the kiosk. What would you do to help prevent this from happening?

Comment: Assume I am an idiot here. I know about non-persistent cookies. I don't know how (I can look up though) to do session timeouts though that is my line of thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets try to fix the users instead of the code :) , i guess that your log out button is like the one here on stackoverflow. its a little text link "logout" some where in the upper right corner. thats perfect for people who use webapps day by day and are aware of the fact that they need to logout before someone comes along a does havoc to thier facebook profile, but less tech savy users wont think of that and walk away.

you need to the get the attention of your users to this logout-button and teach them that logging-out is a good thing.

try the following

- give the logout button more visual weight then usally make it bigger, make it a real button instead of a textlink and even change its color to something more alerting (red, orange, ... whatever fits your ci)
- if they dont loggout, use the session timeout and some javascript the refresh the page after any amount of inactivity, but also set a flag that this user has not logged out after his last visit. that way you can greet him on his next login with a nice confirmation dialog, and tell him once again why logging out is so important and where your logout-button is located.

Comment: I like the idea of a more noticeable log out button. I think I'll do that along with the jQuery timeout I have already implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution would be to enforce a timeout. If there's no activity from the user within a certain time limit (say, a minute or so), log them out. Of course, this won't prevent someone from walking up immediately after an employee is done and seeing how much money they make.

ATMs handle this, I think, by timing out after a minute or two, which isn't super-secure but at least offers some minimal security.

If the employees have any kind of RFID card or other security token, you could require them to put it in a reader slot, and log them out whenever the card disappears. Handling this within a web app, though, could get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to use a little javascript.

Just have it set to something like 30 seconds of inactivity.  If the user hasn't clicked on anything have the javascript send it back to a login page.

Here's [a link](http://www.beyondfusion.com/html/tutorial-autoclose.php) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already thought of the obvious (aggressive session timeouts, non-persistent authentication cookies, etc); how about a bit of an "out there" suggestion?

I'm not sure how do-able this would be with a web-based interface; but what about using some form of IR sensor with a usb/serial interface and an API you can tie into? This may make it possible to invoke some form of "logout" operation when someone walks away from the kiosk.

Perhaps someone has a better suggestion for external hardware, but this was the first thing that lept to my mind as a out-of-the-box approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [jQuery version](http://philpalmieri.com/2009/09/jquery-session-auto-timeout-with-prompt/) that seems to work quite well. I'll start by using that and see how that goes.